# error installing qt-sdk on linux

Tags: qt

i have ubuntu-10.10 desktop version i installed following packages using apt-get install

1. libglib2.0-dev
2. libSM-dev
3. libxrender-dev
4. libfontconfig1-dev
5. libxext-dev
6. libgl1-mesa-dev
7. libglu-meas-dev

i downloaded qt-sdk-linux-x86-opensource-2010.05.1.bin

changed permission of bin file
chmod u+x qt-sdk-linux-x86-opensource-2010.05.1.bin
./qt-sdk-linux-x86-opensource-2010.05.1.bin

it gives me an error like not able to create symbolic link to libQtCore-4.7.0 and installation aborts.

can any one suggest me what is going wrong and how can i over come this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can just install `qt-sdk` package from Ubuntu repositories, if you must install by hand, try running it with `sudo`;

```
sudo ./qt-sdk-linux-x86-opensource-2010.05.1.bin
```

Comment: i tried installing as super user only but still got error as i mentioned above

Comment: thanks for your help i could install using ubuntu software center

Comment: i get dialog box telling this "unable to create symbolic link /opt/qtsdk-2010-05/lib/libQtOpenGL.so.4.7 -> libQtOpenGL.so.4.7.0" could you help me out solve this issue.

Comment: What does `ls -al /opt/qtsdk-2010-05/lib/` say?